# unable to login to heroku in command prompt

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

```
Program Files\heroku>heroku login
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: g123mail@gmail.com
Password: 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

> Error: spawnSync sh ENOENT
>       at notFoundError (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/enoent.js:6:26)
>       at Object.verifyENOENTSync (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/enoent.js:48:16)
>       at Function.spawnSync [as sync] (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:29:43)
>       at Promise (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/password-prompt/index.js:78:26)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at Object.notty (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/password-prompt/index.js:75:12)
>       at Object.raw (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/password-prompt/index.js:11:71)
>       at Object.hide (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/password-prompt/index.js:7:21)
>       at Object.prompt (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/password-prompt/index.js:109:30)
>       at _prompt (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/cli-ux/lib/prompt.js:69:35)

Comment: Did you install the latest version from the official site at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli?

Comment: Yes. I have installed latest version

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: No, I didn't solve it.